# Empty field in CSV file (with regex)

Tags: regex, powershell, csv, pattern-matching

I have a CSV file with this informations :

```
RIEN;ADRIEN;CECI EST UN EXEMPLE DU RIEN;RIEN;AUTRE VALEUR
VALEUR;RIEN DE CELA N'EST POSSIBLE;ADORIEN;VALEUR;RIEN
```

I would set at blank field when the value match "RIEN" :

```
;ADRIEN;CECI EST UN EXEMPLE DU RIEN;;AUTRE VALEUR
VALEUR;RIEN DE CELA N'EST POSSIBLE;ADORIEN;VALEUR;
```

I try make and test in https://regex101.com/, several regex. My lasted test is :

```
(^RIEN)(?=;)|((?=;)(RIEN)(?=;))*|(?=;)(RIEN$)
```

I want only "RIEN" value, without semicolon character

In the futur, I like delete all paterns inlued in array, with a PowerShell script:

```
        $deleteCharacters = @(
                    "RIEN",
                    "VALUE WITH SPACE"
        )
        foreach ($deleteWord in $deleteWords) {
                    while ($line.Contains($deleteWord)) {
                    $line = $line.Replace($deleteWord, "")
        }
```

Somebody to help me, please ?

Regards,

Comment: `$line -replace "[^;]*\bRIEN\b[^;]*", ""` - if you want to remove 0+ non-`;`s, a whole word `RIEN`, and again 0+ non-`;`s.

Comment: import the csv file, loop over the fields, test the values and replace them if needed. Regexes have nothing to do here.

Comment: Thank you ! it's work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete all the unneeded values with just one regexp without even iterating by lines:

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText('c:\path\input.txt') `
     -replace '(^|[;\r\n])\s*(RIEN|"VALUE IN QUOTES"|VALUE WITH SPACES)([;\r\n]|$)',
              '$1$3' | Out-File c:\path\output.txt -encoding UTF8
```